# How to delete column from db without having migrations enabled?

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, database-migration

I have a .net core 2.1 application in which I have a small SqlServer 2016 database that contains only one table i.e Product.

Now I have a DbContext like:

```
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
      public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options)
      {

      }

      public virtual DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
```

and the product model:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
        [DataMember]
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
    }
```

and in Program.cs file I am calling this like:

```
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
var context = services.GetRequiredService<DataContext>();
context.Database.EnsureCreated();
```

Now the issue is I don't have migrations enabled in my project and I want to remove 2 columns i.e CreatedBy and UpdatedBy from by db. But I have to delete the table so the changes can be reflected. Is there anyway to do that without deleting the table?  Like what we do when we have migrations enabled. 
`Add-Migration` and `Update-Database`. Can I do this with `context.Database>EnsureCreated()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible without having migrations enabled. So I have enabled migrations in my application and changed `context.Database.EnsureCreated()` to `context.Database.Migrate()` and now everything is working as expected.